# How to use a Servlet to call an EJB from same application

Tags: web-services, servlets, ejb, weblogic, ejb-2.x

I am trying to call a method in an EJB from a servlet that is hosted in the same application.

However the exception I am getting is that my application cannot find the JNDI I am passing in the `initialContext.lookup()` method, and I have tried many. I think maybe the JBDI is not being declared properly in the XML. Does anyone know how to add the JNDI as a global variable in the weblogic-xml?

Here is the xml files for the ejb-jar and weblogic-ejb-jar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhd6k.jpg

And here is my servlet:

```
AdminServiceLocalHome admin_Home = getAdminHome(); //does jndi lookup to get adminhome

AdminServiceLocal adminLocal  = admin_Home.create(); //creates() ejb

String output =  adminLocal.sendPendingResolutions(); //calls ejb
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to add this line to the xml jar:

```
<wls:jndi-name>services.Admin</wls:jndi-name>
```

and use the above JNDI